# Creating fake URL in Java

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I am working on an `ERP` project.
We have a URL like this: `domain.com/home-appns`
keeping this URL for the request I want to display another URL in address bar like: `domain.com\home\home-appns`.

I an looking for solutions using Java/javascript.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a way to make the browser's address bar show something other than the URL of the page that is currently being displayed.

That limitation is probably a **good thing**, since it would allow nasty websites to spoof the user.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for [`URLRewriting`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_rewriting)? It can be done using JSPs or Servlets.

I am not sure if you can do this properly using Javascript, but you can change the address of the page using, but I would suggest using it at Server Side.

Check out the [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_rewriting) on Wikipedia to get a fair info on it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a servlet and in web.xml, where the servlet is defined, add tag `url-pattern`. Write corresponding url pattern in it. In this servlet, now use `response.sendRedirect("URL")`. Now your browser will show `url-pattern` instead of `URL`.